# What language feature in Ruby are Rails controller filters implemented in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep seeing this feature used in different places but I don't even know what to search for.  In Rails controllers they're filters like `before_filter`, in Sidekiq workers its `sidekiq_options`.  But what is the generic name for the `class` feature that this uses.  Class method?

```
class ShoppingController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :verify_open_shop
end
```

```
class WorkerOne
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options unique_across_workers: true, queue: 'default'

  def perform(args); end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are both methods of classes. You can see them in methods lists.

```
> ShoppingController.methods.include?(:before_filter)
=> true
> WorkerOne.methods.include?(:sidekiq_options)
=> true
```

It's possible to get some information about a particular [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Method.html)

```
ShoppingController.method(:before_filter)
```

Also, you can list instance methods public and private ones:

```
ShoppingController.instance_methods
ShoppingController.private_instance_methods
```

Comment: Just a heads up, `before_filter` was deprecated in Rails 5 and has been removed in Rails 6, `before_action` is the way to go now.